# Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a problem in which there are `M` users that have to choose over a set of `N` possible choices. I want to estimate the average probability that `n` items are not chosen by anyone. I modeled this as a Bernoulli distribution like:

$$P(n=k) = \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{N}\right)^{M*k}\left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{N}\right)^M\right)^{N-k}$$

and then I multiply and sum:

$$ A = \sum_{i=1}^{N} i * P(n = i) $$

However, I also implemented a small program which empirically shows this, and I see that as `M` increase, I get some small errors (like 2-3 %). I am wondering whether I missed something in the Bernoulli modeling, as I am 100% sure of my small program, or if something different to Bernoulli have to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of $n=k$ items not chosen at all after $M$ random choices from $N$ with replacement is $$\Pr(n=k)=S_2(M,N-k) \dfrac{ N!}{k! \, N^M} $$ where $S_2$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

The expected number of gaps $E[n] = \sum_k k \Pr(n=k)$ is easier to calculate another way: the probability that a particular item is not chosen by an individual is $1-\frac{1}{N}$ so that it not chosen by $M$ people is $\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^M$ and so the expected total number not chosen is $$E[n]=N\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^M.$$